# Error encounterd while running Firefox in Xvfb: "Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99"."

Tags: firefox, xvfb

I'm trying to run Firefox in Headless mode in a CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

I have already have firefox-45.3.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 installed.

I have run the following commands for the configurations:

```
// install Xvfb package
yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
// add screen resolution
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
// add Display
export DISPLAY=:99
// run firefox
firefox
```

After running the firefox,  have encountered this error:
**"Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99"."**

I have tried to add this extension using:

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension RANDR &
```

But stil, the same error persist when I attempt to run the firefox again.

How can I add RANDR in Xvfb when running in firefox?

Thanks for the response in advance.